# Variable p passed by reference before being initialized

Tags: swift, pass-by-reference

I have a Human class with a function that takes any amount of people and determines if someone is older than any of those people, then returns an array with the people he/she is older than.

```
func isOlderThan(people: Human...) -> [Human] {
    var p: [Human]

    for person in people {
        if age > person.age {
            p.append(person)
        }
    }
    return p
}
```

However at

```
p.append(person)
```

I'm getting the error

```
Variable p passed by reference before being initialized
```

Anyone sure why this is? Thanks!

Comment: And if you don't _upvote_ nor _accept_ answers, people will be less motivated to help you - rewards acting as they do.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Your declaration of p is just that, a declaration. You haven't initialised it. You need to change it to

```
var p = [Human]()
```

Or, as @MartinR points out,

```
var p: [Human] = []
```

There are other equivalent constructs, too, but the important thing is you have to assign something to the declared variable (in both cases here, an empty array that will accept `Human` members).

**Update**
For completeness, you could also use:

```
var p: Array<Human> = []
```

or

```
var p = Array<Human>()
```

Comment: but why does it say: " passed by reference"?

Comment: @Honey I'm not a compiler-level guru, but I expect that the way the `.append` method is implemented in `Array` uses a reference to `p` to change it.

Answer (score 2):

`append` is a `mutating` method of the struct `Array`.

You can think of a struct method as a function with a hidden `self` parameter. By default, parameters to functions are constants, and therefore you cannot do anything to it that you cannot do to a constant. A `mutating` struct method needs to do things that cannot be done to a constant, therefore, it must take the `self` parameter as `inout`, i.e. as if it's passed by reference. Thus, you can only call a mutating method on something you can pass by reference. And you cannot pass an uninitialized variable by reference.

Comment: but why does it say: " passed by reference"?

Comment: @Honey: The compiler probably treats struct method calls as function calls, which means it treats mutating struct function calls as functions calls with a parameter passed by reference.

Comment: hmmm...you mean to the compiler `person.updateAddress(to:newAddress)` is treated as something like: `Person.updateAddress(person:&person, to:newAddress)`?

Comment: @Honey: basically

Answer (score 1):

You are better off simply using the `filter` method:

```
func isOlderThan(people: Human...) -> [Human] {
  return people.filter { self.age > $0.age }
}
```

It works like this:

```
 20> class Human {
 21.     let age : Int
 22.     init (age: Int) { self.age = age }
 23.     func isOlderThan (people: Human...) -> [Human] {
 24.         return people.filter { self.age > $0.age }
 25.     }
 26. }

 28> let me = Human(age:27)
me: Human = {
  age = 27
}

 29> me.isOlderThan (Human(age:25), Human(age:30))
$R10: [Human] = 1 value {
  [0] = {
    age = 25
  }
}
```

By the way, before long you'll find it useful to define an additional method specified as:

```
func isOlderThan(people: [Human]) -> [Human] { ... }
```

because as soon as you have an array and since there is no `apply` method yet in Swift, your original method won't work.