# Using arrays of arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, integer

Still pretty new to Swift I want to use an array of arrays of integers. I thus write the following in the function that makes use of it.

```
var allSetsOfCards: [[Int]]
```

I don't know before the app starts running what exactly will be in it or how big it will be except that each array in it will contain three integers so I can't specify exactly what it will look like when I introduce it. Later I want to add some information to it in the following way:

```
allSetsOfCards[setNumber][0] = i
allSetsOfCards[setNumber][1] = j
allSetsOfCards[setNumber][2] = k
```

where `setNumber`, `i`, `j`, and `k` are integer-variables. This gives me the error message:

> Variable 'allSetsOfCards' passed by reference before being
>   initialized.

What do I need to do? I searched this site and found one entry that seemed to cover the topic ([Two-dimensional array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127700/two-dimensional-array-in-swift)) but I was unable to understand it. No amount of googling seems to work either. An answer to my specific problem would be great. A brief easy to understand explanation of how swift handles arrays would be terrific.

Comment: you can use my answer from a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/49735414/7435893

Answer (score 4):

The error message is pretty clear.
What you done here is just the declaration. To use it you need initialize it either separate from declaration:

```
var allSetsOfCards: [[Int]]
allSetsOfCards = [[Int]]()
```

or along with it:

```
var allSetsOfCards = [[Int]]()
```

The next problem would raise when compiler reaches your subscript code. Since the array is pretty empty in the beginning, you'll get `Index out of range` error. You should either reserve capacity to be able to subscript your indexes, or append your elements to an empty array.

```
allSetsOfCard.append([i, j, k])
```

Answer (score 1):

*Although your question could be a duplicate of: [Variable p passed by reference before being initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838015/variable-p-passed-by-reference-before-being-initialized), I would try to post a descriptive answer to your case.*

What you have done so far by implementing:

```
var allSetsOfCards: [[Int]]
```

is just *declaring a variable without [initializing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)) it*. So what you have to do is to initialize it before using it, you would have more than one option to do this, you could simply do it like this:

```
var allSetsOfCards = [[Int]]()
```

That would fine if you are pretty sure that `allSetsOfCards` will be always used.

Sometimes your application won't need to work with it, for instance imagine that you'll need to fill `allSetsOfCards` if only specific condition(s) has/have been applied then the initialization of it would be meaningless (it is a useless wasting of memory), at this point you could declare it as *lazy property*:

```
lazy var allSetsOfCards = [[Int]]()
```

assuming that `allSetsOfCards` is a property of a struct or a class, at this point it won't be initialized unless you need to use it.

---

**Aside note:**

Also, you have to make sure that the inner arrays are also already initialized, example:

```
var allSetsOfCards = [[Int]]()

// that's what I mean:
var firstSet = [Int]()

allSetsOfCards.append(firstSet)

// assuming that `setNumber` is 0 so far...
var setNumber = 0

allSetsOfCards[setNumber].append(i)
allSetsOfCards[setNumber].append(j)
allSetsOfCards[setNumber].append(k)

// OR (as shorter option):
allSetsOfCards[setNumber].append([i, j, k])
```

<sub>Do you know Swift *does* has [Sets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set)? You might want to let `allSetsOfCards` to be an array of sets (`[Set<Int>]()`) instead .</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

**you can initialize array of array like this**

`var intArrayOfArray: [[Int]] = [[Int]]()`

**below line will throw an error because at this point the array is only initialised and does not contain any element, hence Array index out of bound error.**

```
 //print(intArrayOfArray[0]) //output:: error indexOutOfBound

intArrayOfArray.append([1,2,3]) 

print(intArrayOfArray[0]) // output:: [1,2,3]

intArrayOfArray.append([4,5])

print(intArrayOfArray[1]) // [4,5]

intArrayOfArray[0] = [6, 7]

print(intArrayOfArray[0]) // [6, 7]
```